# Help with \regex_match_case

Tags: latex3, l3regex

I am in need of some explanation regarding Regex in Latex3, mainly, why am I having difficulties searching for a specific expression within a token list. If I write it as:

```
\regex_match_case:nnTF {
    { SC }{ MHM~ }
    { [b-dq-w] }{ NOPE~ }
}{ SC70-6C }
{ OK~ }
{ nOK~ }
```

there are no problems, I get the right output (MHM and OK). But if I insert that text as `\tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { SC70-6C }` I get "nOK", even though in log I can see that the right text is in (SC70-6C). Tried also converting "tl" into string and still get the same "nOK".

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set:Npn \l_tmpa_cs
{
%these work 
%   \regex_match:nnTF { b [cde]* } { abecdcx } { TRUE~ } { FALSE~ }
%   \regex_match:nnTF { [b-dq-w] } { example } { TRUE~ } { FALSE~ }
    
%   \regex_match_case:nnTF {
%       { b [cde]* }{ YES~ }
%       { [b-dq-w] }{ NO~ }
%   }{ abecdcx }
%   { OK~ }
%   { nOK~ }

%   \regex_match_case:nnTF {
%       { SC }{ MHM~ }
%       { [b-dq-w] }{ NOPE~ }
%   }{ SC70-6C }
%   { OK~ }
%   { nOK~ }

%does not work; I always get nOK
    \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { SC70-6C }
    \tl_set:Nx \l_tmpb_tl { \l_tmpa_tl }
    %\tl_set:Nx \l_tmpb_tl { \tl_to_str:N { \l_tmpa_tl } }
    
    \tl_log:N \l_tmpa_tl
    
    \regex_match_case:nnTF {
        { SC }{ MHM~ }
        { [b-dq-w] }{ NOPE~ }
    }{ \l_tmpb_tl }
    { OK~ }
    { nOK~\tl_log:N \l_tmpb_tl }
}

\cs_set_eq:NN \DoStuff \l_tmpa_cs%

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
    \DoStuff
\end{document}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second argument to `\regex_match_case:nnTF` is specified as `n`, so it wants an “explicit” token list.

If you want to pass the contents of a token list variable, you do

```
\prg_generate_conditional_variant:Nnn \regex_match_case:nn {nV} {T,F,TF}
```

and after that your code can be

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\prg_generate_conditional_variant:Nnn \regex_match_case:nn {nV} {T,F,TF}

\cs_new_protected:Npn \maag_dostuff:
  {
    \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { SC70-6C }
    \tl_set:Nx \l_tmpb_tl { \l_tmpa_tl }
    
    \regex_match_case:nVTF
      {
        { SC }{ MHM~ }
        { [b-dq-w] }{ NOPE~ }
      }
      \l_tmpb_tl
      { OK~ }
      { nOK~\tl_log:N \l_tmpb_tl }
}

\cs_set_eq:NN \DoStuff \maag_dostuff:

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\DoStuff

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note `protected` because the function does unexpandable jobs; also, functions should not have an `l_` or `g_` prefix and *must* have a signature.

Also, `\cs_set_protected:Npn` should be `\cs_new_protected:Npn`. Use the former only if you know that the defined function *should* be redefined without notice.

Comment: Thank you @egreg for explanation and fix. Did not know I can also tweak signatures of predefined functions (\regex_match_case).

Comment: @MAAG That's one of the most important features of `expl3`, which avoids thinking about `\expandafter`. For instance, the kernel defines `\cs_set_eq:NN` and then does `\cs_generate_variant:Nn \cs_set_eq:NN { cN, Nc, cc }`